# javascript table cell not update and I have a row index

Tags: javascript

The Error given is that `a.updateRow` and `row.updateCell` are not a function.

Please tell the appropriate method to update cell in this.

```
 function edittable(t) {        // t is row index 

    var a = document.getElementById("myTableData");
    var x = document.getElementById("<%= txtvalue1.ClientID %>").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("<%= txtvalue2.ClientID %>").value;

    var rowCount = t;  //a.rows.length;
    var row = a.updateRow(rowCount);
    //alert(row);

    row.updateCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
    row.updateCell(1).innerHTML = "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Update\" onClick=\"Javacsript:updateRow(this ,'" + x + "','" + y + "');\">";
    row.updateCell(2).innerHTML = x;
    row.updateCell(3).innerHTML = y;


    var b = document.getElementById("<%= ADD.ClientID %>");
    b.value = "btnadd";
}
```

Comment: There is no updateRow method available on the element. DId you mean another method?

Comment: what are you trying to do by updaterow

Answer (score 0):

There are no such methods as updateRow and updateCell in javscript as far as I can see - 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tablerow.asp. You can get the rows collection using a.rows and cells in a row r using r.cells collection and then update. But I'd strongly suggest using jQuery or one such library.

Comment: a.rows is not working..Please tell another method to update row

Comment: It works in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58TFw/) i created. The only problem i can see is table missing from DOM or not having correct id.